# How to write the symbol for begin/end expression inside RichString?

Tags: xtend

How do I write the symbol **»** from within an Eclipse environment with Xtend, in order to obtain this code:

```
def writeLetterTo(Person p) '''
    Dear «p.forename»,

    bla bla foo

    Yours sincerely,

    Joe Developer

        «signature»
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bound to CTRL+> and also available through code completion.
An a mac it's also bound to ALT+SHIFT+Q

Answer (score 0):

On my linux,

`CTRL+SHIFT+<`

and

`CTRL+SHIFT+>`